# Can I retrieve `app` instance to configure the event of the nest module inside the module or service in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the `app` instance in order to configure the event of the Nest module from within the module itself or an injectable service. I am interested in adjusting the module configuration based on certain conditions. Currently, I am using the `onInit` lifecycle hook of the Nest module and the `configure` method of `NestModule`. However, these hooks do not provide access to the app instance for configuration. Is there a way to retrieve the app instance within the module or service, outside of the bootstrap process? Currently, it seems to be possible only during the bootstrap phase.

Comment: There's no way to inject the app instance into the app itself, that doesn't make much sense to do. What are you trying to configure? Also, `configure` is for setting up middleware not for configuring anything of the application

Comment: I am enabling swagger. Now I am doing reusable bootstrap builder using.